# How to apply joins between MongoDb Collection in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core-2.0

I am taking simple example to demonstrate my problem, There are 2 class in C#

```
class Table1
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId _Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

class Table2
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId _Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement]
        public int Age { get; set; }

        [BsonElement]
        public ObjectId UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

Below is the data in MongoDB:
**Table1:**

> {"_id":"5bbd9b904b235724d42d61b1","Name":"User1"}

**Table2:**

> {"_id":"5bbd9bad4b235724d42d61b2","Age":25,"UserId":"5bbd9b904b235724d42d61b1"}

Now making join in c# console application

```
static void ViewRecords()
    {
        MongoContext db = new MongoContext();
        var Table1 = db._database.GetCollection<Table1>("Table1");
        var Table2 = db._database.GetCollection<Table2>("Table2");

        var r = from t1 in Table1.AsQueryable()
                join t2 in Table2.AsQueryable() on t1._Id equals t2.UserId into result
                select new Table1()
                {
                    _Id = t1._Id,
                    Name = t1.Name
                };

        foreach (var a in r)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.Name);
        }
    }
```

Now it is throwing the exception

> The GroupJoin query operator is not supported.

The links i have followed:[Link](https://www.axonize.com/blog/joining-collections-mongodb-using-c-driver-linq/) .

I have installed mongocsharpdriver 2.7.0 and MongoDB.Driver 2.7.0 thru nuget package manager.
I am banging my head on wall from past 2 days over this.. any support will be really appreciated.

Comment: BTW - why join if you are not using anything from `Table2`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities

Comment: @GiladGreen, we just need table1 data based on inner join...although we could use the result too but here i just want to know why its not working..

Comment: @S.Akbari, any another way around to achieve the results?

Comment: **Joins** are for Relational databases, Document databases are not meant to have **Joins**.
You should run do you joins in C# code, it is not necessary to  convert to AsQueryable() for joining two collections using C# code

Comment: Sounds like you  need to use SQL :)

Answer (score -1):

As i was trying again and again, I found something very interesting. Same seems to be working fine after few major changes.
1. Change MongoClient to IMongoClient and MongoDatabase to IMongoDatabase

```
public class MongoContext
    {
        IMongoClient _client;
        public readonly IMongoDatabase _database;

        public MongoContext()
        {
            //Reading credentials from Web.config file
            _client = new MongoClient("mongodb://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoHost"] + ":" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoPort"]);
            _database = _client.GetDatabase(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoDatabaseName"]);
        }
    }
```

I need to remove MongoServer from my context class.

2. Change ViewRecords Method to below:

   ```
       static List<Table1> ViewRecords()
   {
       try
       {
           MongoContext db = new MongoContext();
           IMongoCollection<Table1> = db._database.GetCollection<Table1>("Table1");
           IMongoCollection<Table2> = db._database.GetCollection<Table2>("Table2");

           var r = from t1 in Table1.AsQueryable()
                   join t2 in Table2.AsQueryable() on t1._Id equals t2.UserId
                   select new Table1()
                   {
                       _Id = t1._Id,
                       Name = t1.Name
                   };

           return r.ToList();
       }
       catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
   }
   ```

Now it worked.. I got this hint from some blog, will share that link if i found the same again.